# if statement based on string field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I have few strings which is "," separated. I need to search and replace the string based on the matched fields. For Eg.

Strings are:

```
MUMBAI,918889986665,POSTPAID,CRBT,CRBT,SYSTEM,151004,MONTHLY,160201,160302
MUMBAI,912398456781,POSTPAID,SEGP30,SEGP30,SMS,151004,MONTHLY,160201,160302
```

I need to write a script which will search and replaces the lines based on field number 4.

Illustration: (sudo code)

```
if [Field4==CRBT]
```

update line1 as:

```
 8889986665,ACT,DEFAULT,1,0,SYSTEM,2016-03-02 00:00:00
```

if [Field4==SEGP30]

update line2 as:

```
   2398456781,ACT,SEGP30_0,3,0,SMS,2015-03-02 00:00:00
```

After all the comparison, desired output should be:

```
 8889986665,ACT,DEFAULT,1,0,SYSTEM,2016-03-02 00:00:00
 2398456781,ACT,SEGP30_0,3,0,SMS,2015-03-02 00:00:00
```

Kindly help me with the shell script.

Comment: I am trying something like this:

    for i in /tmp/subs.txt
do
    cut -d, -f 2,4 $i > /tmp/subs1.txt
done

while read line
do
    if [[ "${fields[4]}" = "CRBT" ]]
    string=",ACT,DEFAULT,1,0,SYSTEM,2016-03-02 00:00:00"
    string="$line${string}"
    echo $string >> "/tmp/subs2.txt"
done < "/tmp/subs1.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `keydata` to store your `if/else` mapping like this (delimited by pipe):

```
CRBT|8889986665,ACT,DEFAULT,1,0,SYSTEM,2016-03-02 00:00:00
SEGP30|2398456781,ACT,SEGP30_0,3,0,SMS,2015-03-02 00:00:00
```

Then use this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} $4 in a{$0=a[$4]} 1' FS="|" keydata FS="," file

8889986665,ACT,DEFAULT,1,0,SYSTEM,2016-03-02 00:00:00
2398456781,ACT,SEGP30_0,3,0,SMS,2015-03-02 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward with `read` and arrays:

```
while IFS=, read -ra fields
do
    if [[ "${fields[4]}" = "CRBT" ]]
    then
        echo "do something"
    elif [[ "${fields[4]}" = "SEGP30" ]]
    then
        echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You *might* need `${fields[3]}` instead; it's not clear from the question if the OP is starting with 0 or 1, and the example input has the same values in the two adjacent columns.

Comment: When all rules are related to field4, I would recommend a `case "${fields[4]}" in` construction.

Comment: @chepner yes field  3 and 4 are same. We can take any. 
>>OP is starting with 0 or 1
Requirement is like, if either field 3 or 4 gets matched in given strings, it just replaces the whole line with desired output.